# Efficient way to truncate string to length N

Tags: c++, string

For example, suppose I have `std::string` containing UNIX-style path to some file:

```
string path("/first/second/blah/myfile");
```

Suppose now I want to throw away file-related information and get path to 'blah' folder from this string. So is there an efficient (saying 'efficient' I mean 'without any copies') way of truncating this string so that it contains `"/first/second/blah"` only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If N is known, you can use

```
path.erase(N, std::string::npos);
```

If N is not known and you want to find it, you can use any of the search functions. In this case you 'll want to find the last slash, so you can use [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) or [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of):

```
path.erase(path.rfind('/'), std::string::npos);
path.erase(path.find_last_of('/'), std::string::npos);
```

There's even a variation of this based on iterators:

```
path.erase (path.begin() + path.rfind('/'), path.end());
```

That said, if you are going to be manipulating paths for a living it's better to use a library designed for this task, such as [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I knew that there must be the _beautiful_ way of doing this :) Thanks.

Comment: I edited the answer, std::string::npos in place of std::npos. npos is a member of std::string not std

Comment: How is it different from `resize` method?

Comment: @mlt: There's no difference really in this scenario.

Comment: The first answer given (fixed length N) fails if the string is already shorter than N, throwing std::out_of_range. substr() does not have this problem.

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer for sure works, the most efficient way to throw away the end of a string is to call the `resize` method, in your case just:

```
path.resize(N);
```

Comment: This will increase the size of the string if it is shorter than N, extending it with null characters that are considered part of the string, which could be very confusing.

Comment: @RichardWhitehead `path.erase(N, M)` will throw an exception, if `N` is larger than the old size of the string. So for both variants, the caller should make sure, that `N` is at most the old size of the string. If `N` refers to the start of a substring inside the original string, this will always be the case.